# replacing malloc/free with new/delete in c++

Tags: c++, memory-management

I just want to be sure.

this is my code

```
int * Image = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * m_Width/2 * m_Height);
free(Image);
```

if I want to use new Instead of malloc and free instead of delete.
this is what i wrote

```
int* Image = new int[m_Width/2 * m_Height];
delete[] Image;
```

Is that correct?

Comment: That is indeed correct. I don't think this is worthy of an answer.

Comment: just making sure i will delete the question

Comment: Don't delete it, this is a good example for anyone else who has the same question.

Comment: Don't cast the result of `malloc` to `(int*)`; the cast will happen automatically. DRY.

Comment: int* image = malloc(sizeof(int)* m_Width/2 * m_Height); ?? @jia103

Comment: `malloc()` returns a `void*`.  In C++, you have to type-cast it.

Comment: Sorry for any wrong info. Is the behavior different in C than C++? [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) is what I was going by. I can't believe how rusty I've gotten after working in C#.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically, it is correct.  However, this is C++ we are talking about, and the C++ way to dynamically allocate an array is to use a `std:vector` instead:

```
std::vector<int> Image(m_Width/2 * m_Height);
```

Or:

```
std::vector<int> Image;
Image.resize(m_Width/2 * m_Height);
```

The memory will be freed automatically when the `std::vector` is destructed when it goes out of scope.

Comment: The original code was allocating an array of `int` values, so you would create a `std::vector` of `int` values.

Comment: Yeah I was just trying to make it clear if someone like the OP was watching the answer.

Answer (score 2):

That's correct. But if you want to gain some additional semantics without getting much OOP overhead, you can use unique_ptr:

```
unique_ptr<int[]> Image(new int[m_Width/2 * m_Height]);
// do something with Image...
Image.Reset(); // call it if you want to free memory manually,
               // or just leave until Image is destroyed.
```